# Does expanding a set of dates into daily data introduce too much auto-correlation?

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, autocorrelation

I am building a model to predict whether a person will cancel an appointment, where the most useful feature is almost definitely the number of days until the appointment. The historical data is in the form of a signup date, confirmation date, a cancel date if they cancelled, and the date of the appointment.

| ID | Signup Date | Confirmation Date | Cancel Date | Appointment Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1/3/2021 | N/A | 1/7/2021 |
| 2 | 2/1/2021 | N/A | 2/3/2021 | 2/7/2021 |

However, at the time of prediction, the available data will look a bit different. We don't know if there will be a confirmation date or a cancel date.

| ID | Signup Date | Confirmation Date | Cancel Date | Appointment Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3/1/2021 | 3/3/2021 | ? | 3/7/2021 |
| 4 | 3/1/2021 | ? | ? | 3/7/2021 |

To solve this, I've "expanded" the initial data into daily data. The above table would become:

| ID | As-Of Date | Days Since Signup | Days Until Appointment | Confirmed | Cancel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/2/2021 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/3/2021 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/4/2021 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/5/2021 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/6/2021 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1/7/2021 | 6 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2/1/2021 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/2/2021 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/3/2021 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 1 |

**Does the amount of autocorrelation in this expanded data make it unsuitable for some or all models?**
My current attempt is a LogisticRegression, which seems to perform well, but I'm concerned about it's ability to generalize.

I'm also worried that the people who signed up earlier are being weighted heavier by having more rows in the expanded data set.